# Laser creating weird patterns on screen when reflected from a vibrating membrane

Tags: experimental-physics, acoustics, vibrations

Me and a few friends were doing an experiment today in which we took a membrane stretched over a speaker, and a small mirror in the center of the membrane. We reflected a laser off the mirror on a screen as we produced pure frequencies from the speaker. The reflected laser on the screen started making weird patterns as we increased the frequency until it became an ellipse, which then changed eccentricities until settling down to one single point.

How do I make sense of these results? And what's the mathematics behind this?

It looked like Lissajous curves to me, but they were not exactly the same.

Comment: The membrane has certain modes with certain frequencies (and damping, and...) so depending on the membrane, where the mirror is, and the driving frequency you have different effects on the mirror.

Comment: @JonCuster Can you provide a reference material? I actually need the mathematics, like how the parameters you mention relate to the curves (If possible, an explicit formula for the curves). And btw, we have the mirror in the center of the membrane.